# Ansible environment variable not visible from host

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

When I set an env variable from an ansible playbook like this:

```
- name: Setting variable
  shell: echo $URL
  environment:
    URL: "{{ URL }}"
```

I would like this variable to be seen from the localhost but it's not the case:

```
echo $URL
```

gives nothing.

How can I make URL visible to the host OS ?

**EDIT**:

- I used register but it's not working as I expected
- I don't only want to verify if the variable is set, I want to use this environment variable from any other application in my host.

Comment: did you use `register` to check if `echo $URL` worked as expected or not?

Comment: Yes I used ``` register: API_PUBLIC_URL ``` but it's not working as expected

Comment: well, its working fine for me, ansible 2.5.2

Comment: I'm using 2.5.0

Comment: Did you set `-vv` on your ansible-playbook call?

Answer (score 0):

Crude workaround -

```
- name: Setting variable
  shell: |
    export URL={{ URL }}
    echo $URL
```

Yeah, I don't like it either, but if you're using shell, it should get you moving.